# Python 3.5 easy_install Pillow Error on Windows 10

Tags: python, easy-install, python-imaging-library

When attempting to install Pillow on a Windows 10 machine running Python 3.5 using easy_installer:

```
    C:\Users\MMG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>easy_install pillow
Searching for pillow
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
Best match: Pillow 2.9.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.9.0.zip#md5=cd4e6286fb28e277954c011c3ce05bc4
Processing Pillow-2.9.0.zip
Writing C:\Users\MMG\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vs9ktc0i\Pillow-2.9.0\setup.cfg
Running Pillow-2.9.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\MMG\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vs9ktc0i\Pillow-2.9.0\egg-dist-tmp-cwgzeemi
Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile: 4 processes
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I've been scouring the internet searching for a solution, and now feel quite inept at problem solving. (Apparently I correlate problem solving with browsing through Questions on StackExchange and Googling error messages?) Such is the nature of programming, no? So, I now prostrate myself before superior developers in search of a solution to my programming woes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news: Pillow 2.9.0 doesn't have Windows binaries for Python 3.5 so it was trying to build the source but failing.

The good news: Pillow 3.0.0 was released yesterday and should have Windows binaries for Python 3.5.